# Unable to trigger firestore changes locally

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just started doing firebase and I need to do something when a new document is created but in functions and I setup cli and started locally but the function is not triggered.

while doing `firebase init` I chose `firestore`,`functions`,`storage`

after that did `firebase login` and `firebase serve --only functions`

and the server is up but whenever I add new document the function is not getting triggered?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with `firebase emulators:start`. This starts emulators for Cloud Functions, Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database and Firebase Hosting. If that doesn't work, please share your code and I can have a look.

The docs may be useful too: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#run_the_emulator_suite

Comment: I started the emulator and all the things are running and when I create a new document the function which should be triggered doesn't work or runs. 
Do I need to change something in my web app to point it to the local emulator?

Comment: Do you see something like this in the logs when you start the emulators:

```
i  functions: Setting up Cloud Firestore trigger "testFirestoreOnCreate"
✔  functions: Trigger "testFirestoreOnCreate" has been acknowledged by the Cloud Firestore emulator.
```

Could you also update your question and add code snippets to make sure this all looks ok? A link to a repo would be very helpful too.